# wsdl contain different links but same complex type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, hp-service-manager

My Question is I have application HP Service Manager they have 2 different links to access wsdl file but wsdl file contain same data same everything. 
how can i used wsdl's as service reference in C# application they import as reference but not create endpoint and binding in app.confg file because complexTyple same in both file how can Microsoft handle this issue.

```
<xs:complexType name="EventOutKeysType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="evsysseq" nillable="true" 
 type="cmn:StringType"/>
 </xs:sequence>
 <xs:attribute name="query" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
 <xs:attribute name="updatecounter" type="xs:long" use="optional"/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="EventOutInstanceType">

 ----------------
 <xs:complexType name="EventOutKeysType">
 <xs:sequence>
 <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="evsysseq" nillable="true" 
  type="cmn:StringType"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="query" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
  <xs:attribute name="updatecounter" type="xs:long" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="EventOutInstanceType">
```

you see they have different links but same xml,
like

```
..../SM/EventOut.wsdl

..../SM/EventManagement.wsdl
```

please advice

Comment: The two databases have the same format : Table Names and Columns.  This is referred to as the database schema.  The XML is defining the Database Name, the Table Names, and the Column names and Column Types.

Comment: No i have 1 database single  table